# Must declare the table variable "@table". in if condition ,any one can solve?

Tags: sql

I'm getting this error:

> Must declare the table variable "@table"

from my code below; in `if` condition. Can anyone solve this problem?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dummyInsert]
    @id INT,
    @table NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table WHERE id = @id) < 1
    BEGIN
        EXEC ('INSERT INTO ['+table +'] ([id])VALUES('''+ @id +''')')
    END
```

Comment: You **cannot** use a variable for a table or column name. If you really must do this "generically", then you need to resort to *dynamic SQL* to accomplish this.

Comment: If you write the IF condition in the EXEC, it will work if you concatenate the table like you did in the insert. This IS vulnerable to SQL Injection and should be avoided OR a safe guard put in place making sure that @table is a valid table/view name by querying sys.objects/tables.

Comment: If you have multiple tables with the same structure, such that it makes sense to try to treat them "generically" as you do here, it's often a sign that they should have been a single table instead (possibly with extra columns to contain data that's currently embedded in those table *names*)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `IF` in dynamic SQL as well.

```
EXEC('
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [' + @table + '] WHERE [id] = ' + @id + ') < 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ['+ @table +'] ([id])VALUES('+ @id +')
        END'
)
```